# getting number from the same line

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I was wondering how you can the scanner can pick up all the different numbers on the same line. my assignment has requires us to compute grade averages and he wants it to be like:

> Enter the number of grades: 5
>
> Enter 5 grades: 95.6 98.25 89.5 90.75 91.56
>
> The average of the grades is 93.13

I think for the scanner to get those number it requires an array? but we haven't learned those. Any help would be awesome! So far I have:

```
// number of grades input
    do {
        System.out.println("Enter number of grades");
        // read user input and assign it to variable
        if (input.hasNextInt()) {
            numGrade = input.nextInt();
            // if user enters a negative grade will loop again
            if (numGrade <= 0) {
                System.out.println("Your number of grades needs to positive! Try again");
                continue;
                // if grade number > 0 set loop to false and continue
            } else {
                cont = false;

            }
            // if user does not enter a number will loop again
        } else {
            System.out.println("You did not enter a number! Try again");
            // get the next input
            input.next();
            continue;
        }
        // only not loop when boolean is false
    } while (cont);
    // user input of grades
    do {
        // prompt user to enter the grades
        System.out.println("Enter the " + numGrade + " grades");
        // assign to input
        if (input.hasNextDouble()) {
            grades = input.nextDouble();
            // check if a grade is a negative number
            if (grades <= 0) {
                // report error to user and loop
                System.out.println("Your grades needs to positive! Try again");
                continue;
                // if user enter acceptable grades then break loop
            } else {
                cont2 = false;
            }
            // check if user entered a number
        } else {
            // if user did not enter number report error
            System.out.println("You did not enter a number! Try again");
            input.next();
            continue;
        }
        // only not loop when boolean2 is false
    } while (cont2);

    // average calculation
    average = grades / numGrade;
    System.out.println(average);

}
```

Comment: `nextInt`, `next`, `nextDouble` etc. all look for the next token on the same line, and will only look at the next line if there are no tokens left on the current line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in your assignment the separate spaces means that you should have each number stored in a specific location or variable.

For example: 
Enter three number : 1 2 3

```
int number1 = input.nextInt();
int number2 = input.nextInt();
int number3 = input.nextInt();
```

now Scanner will read by nextInt() method. if it read space then will finished saving value in that variable.

Another Example that read array elements:

Enter three number: 1 2 3

```
int[] myArray = new int[3];
for(int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){
   myArray[i] = input.nextInt();
}
```

Note that the loop will run 3 times as the length of the array.
Also note in the code that input reference for Scanner class but I didn't declare it.

Comment: Thank you! I kinda used a little of both!

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest this

```
// separates the line you send by spaces if you send the next line
// 95.6 98.25 89.5 90.75 91.56 it will create an array like this
// {"95.6","98.25", "89.5","90.75", "91.56"} 
String []grades = input.nextLine().split(' ');
double total=0;
for(int i=0;i<grades.length;i++){
  //parse each value to double and adds it to total
  total+=Double.parseDouble(grades[i]);

}
double average= total/grades.length;
```